# When catching error I got in try block invalid status_code

Tags: php, laravel

In laravel 9 app I try to catch different type of error in try block :

```
<?php
        try {
            $jsonResponse = $articleCrudRepository->update(id: $id, data: [
                ...
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception | \Error | ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            return [
                'status_code' => in_array(class_basename($e),  ['Error', 'ErrorException']) ? $e->getCode() : $e->getStatusCode(),
                'message'     => 'Error updating article : ' . $e->getMessage()
            ];
        }
```

I got valid 'status_code' with valid 'message' in case when I got ModelNotFoundException, but
in case of $articleCrudRepository->NonexistingMethod is called I got 0 in 'status_code' with valid 'message'. Not sure which code must be here, as it is php Error class ?
in case nonexisting var inside of $articleCrudRepository->update is called I got 0 in 'status_code' with valid 'message', but I expected 500 in 'status_code'.

**ADDITIVE CODE :**

I would try to use $jsonResponse var under } catch block, like :

```
try {
    $jsonResponse = $articleCrudRepository->update(id: $args['id'], data: [
       ...
    ], makeValidation: false);
} catch (\Exception | \Error $e) /*( use ($jsonResponse) */ { // I CAN NOT PASS $jsonResponse  like that with  “use”
    return [
       // I would make like line below, but $jsonResponse is not accessible here, as this code could be different and I would like to pass it
        'status_code' => !empty($exceptionCode) ? $exceptionCode : $jsonResponse->getStatusCode(),
        'message'     => 'Error updating article : ' . $e->getMessage()
    ];
}
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: Wow, this question is so difficult to read. Can't you just copy/paste the real error + stacktrace from laravel.log in your original question?

Comment: What makes you think  Error or ErrorException should have some HTTP related error code ? Just set it yourself instead of getting from getCode()

Comment: I which way can I set it ?

Comment: Just open your PHP editor, delete $e->getCode() and type 500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `getStatusCode()` is not a method that exists in [`\Exception`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php), [`\Error`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.error.php) or [`\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException`](https://laravel.com/api/10.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/ModelNotFoundException.html). So `'status_code' => in_array(class_basename($e),  ['Error', 'ErrorException']) ? $e->getCode() : $e->getStatusCode(),` should just be `'status_code' => $e->getCode()`.

Second, `getCode()` refers to the `Exception`'s $code property which defaults to 0. This property is optional. Laravel doesn't seem to use it. It is not an HTTP code.

Third, `\Exception | \Error | ModelNotFoundException` can be replaced by `\Exception | \Error` since `ModelNotFoundException` is an `Exception`. And this is a the same as [`Throwable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.throwable.php) as
[Your Common Sense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587) stated in a comment.

Comment: Thank you ! I got your point .
 $e->getCode() and HTTP code of $jsonResponse are different
Please look at ADDITIVE CODE :